# Error during constructing the argument parse and parse the arguments

Tags: python

Why my argument parse has an error although I have already defined the arguments

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to the input image")
ap.add_argument("-w", "--width", type=float, required=True,
    help="width of the left-most object in the image (in inches)")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

and the error says that

```
usage: main.py [-h] -i IMAGE -w WIDTH
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image, -w/--width
```

Comment: at the time of running main.py, you need to pass the required argument via CLI

Comment: you need to pass `-i/--image root/path_to_image -w/--width some_integer` from the terminal.